# Defining a date x-axis in a scatter plot (R)

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I want to produce a scatterplot of a dataframe which has a date column. The x axis should be monthly divided, or for each 2 months in the last 2 years.

**The dataframe:**

```
code_1000 <-
  as.data.frame(cbind(
    c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
    c("344", "344", "73", "73", "71", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
    c("9-02-2017", "10-01-2016","9-02-2014", "25-03-2015", "9-02-2017",
      "10-06-2017", "8-04-2017", "25-08-2016", "07-08-2017", "15-09-2016"
    )
  ))
names(code_1000) <- c("number", "code", "date")
```

**The plot code:**

```
qplot(data=code_1000,
      x=format(as.Date(date),"%b/%Y"), 
      y=code,
      geom=c("point"),
      na.rm=TRUE,
      xlab="Emission date", ylab="Code",
      size=1, col=2)+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none")
```

I want to plot `code` on the y axis and `date` on the x axis. How can I force the x axis to be monthly divided? Also, when I run my plotting code, the x axis format looks like mm/dddd, but I want mm/yyyy. Why am I getting that format?

I have ~50 dataframes like `code_1000` in a Shiny app.  To make things simpler, I'm not sharing all of the code.

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default date parser is just confused by your DD-MM-YYY notation. 
If you parse the dates with lubridate, the x-axis looks more reasonable (although possibly not with the major/minor ticks you want.)

*I removed your reformatting of the dates inside of qplot and added a scaling function.*

```
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

# implicit in poster's question
library(ggplot2)

code_1000$date <- lubridate::dmy(as.character(code_1000$date))

qplot(
  data = code_1000,
  x = date,
  y = code,
  geom = c("point"),
  na.rm = TRUE,
  xlab = "Emission date",
  ylab = "Code",
  size = 1,
  col = 2
) + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") + scale_x_date(
  date_breaks = "1 year",
  date_minor_breaks = "1 month",
  labels = date_format("%m-%Y")
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up very similar to @MarkMiller above, except my attempt at lubridate failed to work. I used `strptime` instead to convert the dates.

```
code_1000$date <- strptime(code_1000$date, format = "%d-%M-%Y")
```

also I find `ggplot` function to be more flexible and succinct, instead of `qplot`. Inside a Shiny app especially, `qplot` might give variable results(?):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales) # needed for date_format()
ggplot(code_1000, aes(date, code)) +
  geom_point(size=2, col="steelblue") + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Emission Date", y="Code") +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m/%Y"))
```

If you want to set the limits to be consistent across Shiny plots, set specific time limits:

```
limits <- strptime(c("01-01-2014", "01-01-2018"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
ggplot(code_1000, aes(date, code)) +
  geom_point(size=2, col="steelblue") + theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Emission Date", y="Code") +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m-%Y"), #minor_breaks = "1 month"
                   date_breaks = "1 year", limits = as.POSIXct(limits))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matt!
When I run the
code_1000$date <- strptime(code_1000$date, format = "%d-%M-%Y")
the date column became <NA>. Do you know the reason why it is happening? Thanks again.

Comment: I can't reproduce- it works fine for me with only base packages up to that point, using everything copied from this page.  try restarting R and do not load any packages- maybe a conflict with a package function?  I did revise my answer to include packages needed for the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer guys!

I am having difficult on applying this date format for my dataframes in Shiny.

Instead of one data frame `code_1000`, I have 51 different dataframes, named  from `code_1000` to `code_1050`. I would like to apply this date format

```
code_1000$date <- lubridate::dmy(as.character(code_1000$date))
```

on all the `date` columns in those dataframes. I was trying to do it using `for`, but it became kind of confusing and didnt work.

```
for (m in 1:nrow(input)){

  assign(paste0("code_",input$code.numbers[m])$date, lubridate::dmy(as.character(eval(parse(text=paste0("code_",input$code.numbers[m])))$date)))

    }
```

Where the `input$code.numbers` is a dataframe that contains the numbers that named the dataframes (from 1000 to 1050). I got the following error:

```
Error in paste0("code_",input$code.numbers[m])$date : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I would like to learn how to do this using `for` and `lapply()` function, as I have read that in R `lapply()` is an easier approach most of times.

Comment: you might want to post this as a different question, as it's significantly different than the original... I'm trying to learn to use purr::map functions for this type problem. if they are all pretty much identical except for a variable, you might merge them into a longitudinal format dataframe which is easier to work with? would need more info to answer